# Scanner Java just reading the first line

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, bufferedreader, filereader

I have a text file like so:

```
1 2
3 7
5 8
```

with 2 numbers on each row. I want to do something different with the first number and the second number. I'm trying to scan through the text file and print the numbers to make sure that I scanned it right. However, only the first two numbers show up (1 4), then an error says:

```
"java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:858)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1497)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2161)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2115)
    at com.company.SCC.input(SCC.java:30)
    at com.company.SCC.<init>(SCC.java:15)
    at com.company.Main.main(Main.java:11)"
```

I don't understand what the problem is and how to scan the document row by row (I recycled the code for the Scanner and it was previously working). I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, any help would be appreciated.

```
try {
        String file = "testcase1.txt";
        FileReader in = new FileReader(file);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(in);
        String s;
        int x;
        while ((s = br.readLine()) != null) {
            Scanner sca = new Scanner(s);
            x = sca.nextInt();
            graph.addVertex(x);
            int y = sca.nextInt();
            graph.addAdjvex(x, y);
            System.out.println(x + " " + y);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: It looks to me like the second line read by the buffered reader is not what you think it is. Have you tried forgetting the scanner for a moment and just printing out the lines that come out of the buffered reader?

Comment: What do you mean by "only the first two numbers show up (1 4)"? File you showed doesn't contain 4. For now I am guessing that your reader returned empty line (maybe one at the end of file) and you are trying to scan it for numbers (which are not there).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
try {
    File file = new File("testcase1.txt");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);
    int x, y;
    while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
        x = sc.nextInt();
        y = sc.nextInt()
        graph.addVertex(x);
        graph.addAdjvex(x, y);
        System.out.println(x + " " + y);
    }
    sc.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Amazing. it worked. Thank you! I was really making it complicated when it didn't need to be.

Answer (score 1):

```
try {
    File file = new File("testcase1.txt");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);
    while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
        int x = sc.nextInt();
        int y = sc.nextInt();
        sc.nextLine();
        graph.addVertex(x);
        graph.addAdjvex(x, y);
        System.out.println(x + " " + y);
    }
    sc.close()

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should call sc.nextLine () to jump to the next line